# Install wasmtime on gitlab CI docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab

I need a wasm runtime to unit test my code on GitLab, so I have the following in my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
default:
  image: emscripten/emsdk
  before_script:
    - curl https://wasmtime.dev/install.sh -sSf | bash
    - source /root/.bashrc
```

The wasmtime.dev script installs the binaries and updates PATH in ~/.bashrc. Running my tests fails with the message `wasmtime: command not found` (specified as below):

```yaml
unit-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bash test.sh
```

What do I need to do to make sure the changes of the wasmtime install script apply? Thanks!

### Edit

Adding `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.wasmtime/bin"` before `bash test.sh` in the `unit-test` job sucesfully got the wasmtime binary on the path, but I'm not quite sure I'm happy with this solution - what if the path of wasmtime changes later on? Shouldn't sourcing `.bashrc` do this? Thanks!

Comment: which user runs the script?

Comment: I *believe* root, though I'm not sure. How can I find that out? I've also tried sourcing `$HOME/.bashrc` instead of specifying /root, if that's what you're getting it - it had no effect.

Comment: try adding `/usr/bin/whoami` as the first step and see the output. If wasmtime was installed under root, the installation folder is going to be `/root/.wasmtime/bin/wasmtime`, and the PATH is going to be updated in `/root/.bashrc`, but if tests are ran from another user `$HOME` is likely not to be equal to `/root`, this `/root/.bashrc` is not going to be sourced.

Comment: @jabbson looks like its root for both

Comment: Can you source /root/.bashrc from test.sh?

Comment: in case you do that you might need to run bash with -i flag to get source to work